# KeystoneJS getting data of user into mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, relation, keystonejs

So I'm trying to build a shop with Keystone step by step. My problem is that I don't know and can't find how to add a relation between order and user into mongodb.

This is the checkout.js

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Order = keystone.list('Order');

exports = module.exports = function (req, res) {

var view = new keystone.View(req, res);
var locals = res.locals;

locals.section = 'checkout';
locals.formData = req.body || {};
locals.validationErrors = {};
locals.orderSubmitted = false;
locals.orderer = req.user; // <-

// On POST requests, add the Order item to the database
view.on('post', { action: 'checkout' }, function (next) {

    var newOrder = new Order.model();
    var updater = newOrder.getUpdateHandler(req);

    updater.process(req.body, {
        flashErrors: true,
        fields: 'sum',
        errorMessage: 'There was a problem submitting your order:',
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            locals.validationErrors = err.errors;
        } else {
            locals.orderSubmitted = true;
        }
        next();
    });
});

view.render('checkout');
};
```

This is the Order.js model

```
var Order = new keystone.List('Order');

Order.add({
     orderer: { type: Types.Relationship, ref:'User' },
     sum: { type: Types.Money, format: '0.0,00' },
     createdAt: { type: Types.Datetime, default: Date.now },
 });
```

This is the User.js model

```
var User = new keystone.List('User');

User.add({
     name: { type: Types.Name, required: true, index: true },
     email: { type: Types.Email, initial: true, required: true, unique: true, index: true },
     password: { type: Types.Password, initial: true, required: true },
});

User.relationship({ ref: 'Order', path: 'orders', refPath: 'orderer' });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to push a User ObjectId in your Order object to be able to use the populate function in order to read your results. For this you can push directly the id as a string and it with auto cast it :

`var newOrder = new Order.model({
  orderer: '560e19e0228dd7ff3a034f19',
  sum: '1.23',
});`

Note, if you need/want to specify that it is an object, you can use mongodb objectId :

`var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;`

`var newOrder = new Order.model({
  orderer: ObjectId('560e19e0228dd7ff3a034f19'),
  sum: '1.23',
});`

And in your updater, add your fields for format validation :

`updater.process(req.body, {
        flashErrors: true,
        fields: 'orderer, sum',
        errorMessage: 'There was a problem submitting your order:',
    },`